# Invalid Cursor State - No current row

Tags: javadb

I am very new to Java, and I am trying to complete one simple task of reading data from a table and passing it to form variables. However, I am getting this frustrating exception:

> Invalid cursor state - no current row;

I tried everything but still no luck. I looked into Google but I'm not getting an answer that will fix this issue. Hope you guys can help.

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   Connection con;
   Statement stm;
   ResultSet rs;

    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
         initComponents();
         DoConnect();   
    }

    public void DoConnect() {
       try{
            String host = "jdbc:derby:studentinfo;create=true";
            String uname = "sudeep";
            String upass = "sunny";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, upass);
            stm = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM APP.STUDENTID";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

            System.out.println("Query executed");

           if(rs.next())
           {      
              // This is where the exception is occurring!!!!!!

              String id = rs.getString("STUDENTID");
              String first = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
              String second = rs.getString("SECOND_NAME");

              ID.setText(id); 
              fnam1.setText(first);
              lnam.setText(second); 

              System.out.println(id);
           }          
       } 

       catch ( SQLException err) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, err.getMessage()); 
           System.out.println("ERROR GETCONNECTION");}
       }
   }
```

Here is the trace generated by the program 
run:
[EL Info]: 2013-09-03 21:14:15.732--ServerSession(552364977)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Info]: connection: 2013-09-03 21:14:16.299--ServerSession(552364977)--file:/Users/vasundhra_sudeep/NetBeansProjects/StudentForm/build/classes/_jdbc:derby:studentinfo;create=truePU login successful
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row.
Invalid cursor state - no current row.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.checkOnRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getColumnType(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at studentform.MainFrame.DoConnect(MainFrame.java:57)
    at studentform.MainFrame.(MainFrame.java:35)
    at studentform.MainFrame$7.run(MainFrame.java:579)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: Update your question to include the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `APP.STUDENTID` has no data in it. Insert at least one record (aka row) of data into that table, run your program again, and see if the same exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do have two records in table AAP.STUDENTID
I created the records manually. I can see the results when I execute the SQL query.